# Custom Spinner At Runtime

Tags: android

I am creating a custom spinner at runtime. after running the application the spinner style has successfully changed, but there are no more drop down when I click on the spinner. Any help would be appreciated.

Code in **styles.xml**

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="@attr/spinner_style">@style/spinner_style</item>
</style>
<style name="spinner_style" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/gradiant_spinner</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">#DFFFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

in **attr.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources> <attr name="spinner_style" format="reference"/></resources>
```

in **MyCustomSpinner**:

```
public class MyCustomSpinner extends Spinner
{
    public MyCustomSpinner(Context context) {
        super(context, null, R.attr.spinner_style);
    }
}
```

in **Activity**:

```
final MyCustomSpinner spinner = new MyCustomSpinner(context);   //INITIALIZE THE SPINNER
spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, lookupValues));
```

Comment: before setadapter check lookupValues size or length

Comment: lookupValues contains data, i am sure because before trying to set a custom Spinner everything was fine (and i am logging the data of the array)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`final MyCustomSpinner spinner = new MyCustomSpinner(context);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);`

`spinner.setAdapter(adapter, lookupValues));
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

if it don't work try to the keyword "final" before `MyCustomSpinner spinner = ..`